# SPICE modeling gas discharge tube using state machine and behavioral resistor

Tags: ltspice, spice, modeling, model, behavioral-source

A [gas discharge tube](https://www.globalspec.com/learnmore/electrical_electronic_components/surge_suppressors/gas_tube_arresters_gta) (GDT) is a state machine which transitions from a high impedance ("normal") state to a low impedance ("glow") state when the potential across its terminals exceeds the spark-over voltage. Older SPICE models of GDTs tend to use [switching](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=S_Voltage_Controlled_Switch) circuitry. [image: https://doi.org/10.1109/TEMC.2008.2004808] In 2008 Julio G. Zola published a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TEMC.2008.2004808) describing a GDT model using only basic electronic components and no explicit switches.[image: Zola(2008)] This model works well. However in [2018](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/lt-journal-article/PbLJournal-V1N1-2018-03-di-LTSpice-GabinoAlonso.pdf), Analog Devices introduced state machine support for LTspice; this together with behavioral resistors seems like a good fit for modeling GDTs ... with something like this:

```
* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*| GDT model based behavioral resistance and state machine
*|     <pin1>-----o-----o----
*|                |     |       
*|               _|_    \      { Vhold / Ileakage    if state = Normal
*|             Cp---    / Rp = { 
*|                |     \      { Vhold / current(Rp) if state = Glow
*|                |     |       
*|     <pin2>-----o-----o----
*|
* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.subckt GDTx pin1 pin2
* -------------------------------------
*| parameters
* -------------------------------------
  .param Vhold        = 15
  .param Capacitance  = 2p
  .param Vspark       = 90
  .param RPval        = 150Meg
* -------------------------------------
*| state machine
*|     _____    if |V(pin1,pin2)| > Itrip   _____
*|    /     \ ---------------------------> /     \
*|   / state \                            / state \
*|   \ Normal/  if |V(pin1,pin2)| < Ihold \ Glow  /
*|    \_____/ <--------------------------- \_____/
* -------------------------------------
  .machine
    .state Normal 0
    .state Glow   1
    .rule  Normal Glow   abs(V(pin1,pin2))>{Vspark}
    .rule  Glow   Normal abs(V(pin1,pin2))<{Vhold}
    .output (machineOUT) state
  .endmachine
  Rx machineOut pin2 1
* -------------------------------------
*| circuitry
* -------------------------------------
  R2 pin1 pin1b 1p
  V2 pin1b pin1c 0 Rser=0
  Bsrc pin1c pin2 R = (1-u(abs(V(machineOut,pin2))))*{RPval} + u(abs(V(machineOut,pin2)))*{Vhold}/abs(I({R2}))
  CP pin1 pin2 {Capacitance}
.ends GDT_behavioral
```

[image]

However, I would rather not have the 1pΩ resistor R2; but when I try to use the current I(V2) instead of I(R2),

```
  Bsrc pin1c pin2 R = (1-u(abs(V(machineOut,pin2))))*{RPval} + u(abs(V(machineOut,pin2)))*{Vhold}/abs(I({V2}))
```

I get "Fatal Error: Analysis:  Time step too small; time = 0.00147989, timestep = 1.2613e-018: trouble with node "v:u1:2#branch""

What should I do to be able to eliminate the resistor R2 but still be able to implement the Bsrc based on current through that node?

LTspice XVII (17.0.19.0 November 25 2020 12:46:47 US Pacific)

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of R2?

Comment: Ignoring radiation transport and atomic interactions, gas discharge requires at least 2 spatial and one time dimension of PDEs coupled to at least 6-dim ODEs to start. A simpler version might use global rate equations that assume spatially averaged densities for the charged particles and neutral atoms and molecules, but even then it still needs to deal with excited and metastable states. Gas discharge is ***way*** more complex than the model you have there. See Lieberman and Lichtenberg's "Principles of Plasma Discharges and Materials Processing."

Comment: BTW It was relatively recently shown that gas discharge tubes can be modelled in the standard framework of Memristive systems. I would suggest you have look into those and the various modelling techniques for them. The main problem with such hard switching models is you will almost certainty run into convergence issues for larger simulations. You need to "soften" things up by adding finite resistances or implement switching using soft/safe approximations of the switching functions.

See this: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/38048565.pdf

Comment: Sounds like you're asking it to divide by the current through itself without any limiting principle to help with the feedback action.  That's what R2 solves, so I don't think you can get rid of it without changing your equation.  It's analogous to the GMIN used behind the scenes in all diode models (and all other PN junctions).  Also, LTspice might already expect and auto-correct this for you, but you're not supposed to enclose reference designators in braces.  For example, `abs(I({R2}))` should be `abs(I(R2))` while `{RPval}` and `{Vhold}` are needed because they are params to be evaluated.